# Почему в laravel (шаблонизатор blade) не подключается файл?

Tags: bootstrap, laravel

master.blade.php (часть кода body):

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
</body>
```

index.blade.php:

```
@extends('master')
   @section('content')
      @for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
          @yield('block') {{ $i }}
      @endfor
   @endsection
```

block.blade.php:

```
@extends('index')
@section('block')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" style="background: red; height: 100px">
            <p>block</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="background: blue; height: 100px">
            <p>block</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

В данном коде в файле master.blade.php написан шаблон веб-страницы. В файле index.blade.php в операторе for вызывается block , описанный в файле block.blade.php. 
ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ: отображение 10 блоков, описанных в файле block.blade.php

РЕЗУЛЬТАТ: цифры 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Что не так?

Исправил....

index.blade.php:

```
 @extends('master')
 @section('content')
    @for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
        @include('block') {{ $i }}
    @endfor
@endsection
```

master.blade.php:

```
<div id="content">
        @yield('content')
</div>
```

block.blade.php:

```
    @extends('index')
@section('block')
    <div class="container">
        <p>block</p>
    </div>
@endsection
```

прии такой вариации пустой белый экран получается....

Comment: `@include('block')` - используй и убери в нем  все кроме  `<div class="container">..</div>` а переменные все подхватятся

Comment: сделал так, как Вы написали.....результат тоже самое ..... 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Comment: Покажи как сделал :)

Comment: добавил кода исправление в вопрос....

Comment: Убери же все кроме div не нужно там ни    `@extends('index')`, `@section('block')`, просто оставь только html

Comment: спасибо огромное, добавляю голос!!!!)))
Можете объяснить почему там @extends не нужно использоывть?

Comment: Потому как extends подключает каркас, а он у вас уже подключен в файле, где вы вызываете `@include('block')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправил файлы по указанию  Orange_shadow и все заработало!Вот готовый работоспособный вариант файлов
index.blade.php:

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
@for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    @include('block') {{ $i }}
@endfor
@endsection
```

master.blade.php:

```
<div id="content">
    @yield('content')
</div>
```

block.blade.php:

```
  <div class="container">
     <p>block</p>
  </div>
```